# in Twisted, wait until connection closed cleanly

Tags: python, twisted

I want to disconnect cleanly, and then stop the reactor. If I do this, however:

```
controller.connection.disconnect()
reactor.stop()
```

then I get a "connection was lost in a non-clean fashion" message. If I insert a `time.sleep(1)` in between them, the connection closes cleanly. How can I wait until the connection is really closed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could listen for a callback from twisted which indicates that the connection has been disconnected.  [This blog](http://blackjml.livejournal.com/23029.html) describes an approach to do this.

Comment: yep worked well once I figured out how it was doing what it did

Answer (score 0):

I have been wondering about the same thing recently, how to disconnect my client in clean way. While the client is a subclass of `LineReceiver` I tried:

[`connector.disconnect()`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.protocol.ClientCreator.html#connectTCP)

`self.factory.close()` (where `factory` is [`IAddress`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.IAddress.html) returned by `Factory`'s `buildProtocol()`)

[`reactor.stop()`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.IReactorCore.html#stop)

but what I actually found in some docs was:

`self.transport.loseConnection()`

and it closes connection cleanly. The question is quite old now, but I hope it would help somebody in the future :)